# Page size for large resources in a RESTful web service?

Tags: web-services, http, rest

I'm developing a RESTful web service with will serve large data sets, paginating the data sets into reasonably sized chunks of JSON.

Specifics of my application aside, are there any general recommendations to consider when choosing a page size?

I understand are often limits on POST size (e.g. 2 MB for Tomcat) , however I'm primarily concerned with GET requests.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There are no general limits. 32-bit machines might have trouble with GET responses over 4 gigabytes though. I suggest you do some testing to see how much your clients can easily download (are they on smartphones in places with spotty connections, or are they academics on the Internet2 ?). You may also allow user-settable pagination (with upper limits you have set to stop your server from dying).